# ¿Cómo uso urllib.request en Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

Estoy aprendiendo sobre scrapping con python por motivos escolares, uso python 2.7 y lo tengo incluido en el PATH de windows(8.1).

Tengo ya un script de prueba el cual usamos en la escuela con WinPython y funciono, pero al tratarlo de usar me genera error en la primer línea:

```
import urllib.request
```

> importError: No module named request.

ya he buscado agregar PIP a python para poder instalar e importar las librerías y aunque sé que en winPython podría funcionar, en teoría importando e instalando todas las librerías debería ser lo mismo.

Comment: Ese import es para Python 3 no para Python 2. No tienes que instalar nada, es biblioteca estándar, simplemente estas usando código de Python 3 en Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La razón es que ese módulo no está disponible para Python 2.7.

Puedes usar `urllib2.urlopen`.

El módulo *urllib2* es el predecesor de `urllib.request`/ `urllib.error` (se ha dividido en esos módulos a partir de Python 3.X).

Más información [sobre urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) y [sobre urllib2.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.html#module-urllib2)